# Can a service repair replace a cracked display on an Olympus SZ-31MR?

Tags: repair, olympus

Earlier today my Olympus SZ-31MR fell out of my shirt pocket onto the table, rolling a few times. It was turned off at the time.

After examination, I noticed that now it has a thin crack on the back display. My assumption is that it is on the LCD display and not the protective glass/plastic, because it does not stretch from top to bottom, but from some 2mm from the top to some 2mm from the bottom (right where the black frames start and finish). I'm sorry, I don't know how to better describe it, but I'm sure you understand what I mean.

The camera is not damaged in any other way, from what I could tell. Focus works fine, zoom too, touchscreen as well.

***Can you tell me from your experience, is it possible to fix this in an Olympus repair shop?*** I am currently away (field work), and I will take it to a repair shop when I get back, but would really appreciate your opinion for now, from your experience, with this or other Olympus cameras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible.  Most LCD displays are simply parts that can be unplugged, removed, and replaced.  See [this German youtube video](https://youtu.be/kpHEW-grYYA?t=1m27s) demoing the disassembly of an SZ-11. Around the 1:30 mark, you'll see how the LCD display is removed during disassembly.

Comment: Many thanks (and for the edit, also!). I will check then with my local repair shop then, and hope that they have, or are able to order, the spare parts to do this.

Comment: Just had a confirmation that it can be repaired, for about 150 USD in my part of the world (Croatia, Europe).